# How to setup difftool to use pager

Tags: git, difftool

If I use a difftool that has simple shell output how to use pager that is set up in `core.pager` .gitconfig section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git help config` says:

```
pager.<cmd>
    If the value is boolean, turns on or off pagination of the output of a particular
    git subcommand when writing to a tty. Otherwise, turns on pagination for the
    subcommand using the pager specified by the value of pager.<cmd>. If --paginate or
    --no-pager is specified on the command line, it takes precedence over this option.
    To disable pagination for all commands, set core.pager or GIT_PAGER to cat.
```

So all you need is to add a `[pager]` section in .gitconfig and to place `difftool = true` there.